# How to print range of values not found in an array?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

Say I have an array of integer values as such:

```
foo = [1, 5, 19, 27]
```

Now say I generate a list of values from 0 to 29 as such:

```
bar = range(30)
```

I want to print the values of **bar** without printing the values listed in **foo**.

How would I go about doing that in Python 2.7?

**[EDIT]**

I figured it out from this question [python - Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

It turns out that my question is the same as *"How to remove duplicates in lists"* but I didn't figure that out when I was asking the question or searching for other questions similar to mine.

To put this question to rest, here's the answer:

```
list(set(bar) - set(foo))
```

That prints the values of **bar** without printing the values of **foo**.

Comment: I have already tried itertools.product and I've already tried nesting for loops to get what I'm looking for.

The issue with itertools.product is that it returns duplicate values which could pose a memory problem for rather large lists of integers.

The issue with nested for loops is that it takes far too long to parse through a rather large list of integers.

Comment: try  **filter(function, iterable)**  
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: @KimChoJapFan Can you comment on the bounds of the range?

Comment: @ShubhamBhattar I suppose I can:

range(30) is equal to all values between 0 and 29.

Answer (score 0):

Good that you figured out the way to solve this. I want to tell you about another way to achieve this, which would work in `O(n)` time but for this the maximum size of the range has to be approximatey `<= 10^7`.

We can create a auxiliary array containing `0`'s. Then in one iteration across `foo` we can flag (mark as `1`) in the `bar` array whether this value is to be printed or not. The remaining array which is filled with `0`'s are the answer. To put this in code:

```
n = 30
foo = [1, 5, 19, 27]
bar = [0]*n

for i in foo:
    bar[i] = 1

for i in xrange(n):
    if bar[i] == 0:
        print i
```